# How to make tmux work on a Google Cloud Platform linux vm?

Tags: linux, tmux, google-cloud-platform

The google docs says GCP uses `tmux` internally to make terminal sessions reattachable, but I cannot get `tmux` to work *for me* when I try to use it myself.

This is all that happens:

```
$ tmux
[exited]
oligofren at dev in ~ 
$ 1;2c
```

It just exists immediately and leaves that weird byte sequence. I would like to have multiple shells without needing to open many browser windows. Using `uname` tells me this is a Debian box, but not much else:

```
3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What's the output of `echo $TMUX`? If it's internally already a tmux session, running tmux inside of it is not recommended (but it works if you set `TMUX= ` to unset the tmux var)

Comment: it's empty. `[[ "$TMUX" == "" ]] && echo yes;
yes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was hard to answer as the answer depended on knowing my custom configuration, which contained some OS X specific code for handling copy-pasting. I resolved this a couple a week after posting and you can see the [entire commit here in my dotfiles repo](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/commit/141e953f83304878eac50c01beb0ac26d45f73f6).

The culprit was the [`reattach-to-user-namespace` utility](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) *previously* needed to have copy-pasting work in OS X. As it was lacking tmux crashed on startup.

See my link to the commit for the modern cross-platform alternatives.